# Fixed position with show / hide at certain heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a script to "show" and "hide" elements at certain positions on a site. I do not like the fact that I am relying on set positions though and would like something a bit more dynamic. If a user resizes the window for example this script will stop working..

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 1200) {
    $('#red-box-what').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('#red-box-what').css('display', 'none');
}
if (scroll >= 2510) {
    $('#red-box-work').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('#red-box-work').css('display', 'none');
}
console.log(scroll);
})


});     
})( jQuery );
```

For reference the website is: http://www.littlestarmedia.com/alpha/

The sections which use this script are "what we do" and "work with us" (the titles wrapped in red boxes).

Any guidance on changing this script would be appreciated...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is attempting to do.  What does the scroll have to do with the size of the window size?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic solution.  When the top of a ROI div hits the top of the browser, it changes the background color of the site.  I hope you are able to build upon this idea:

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/seibert_cody/sng9emjp/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="section"></div>     
    <div id="red" class="roi"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
    <div id="green" class="roi"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
    <div id="blue" class="roi"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
    <div id="yellow" class="roi"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var ROI = function($div, color){
        this.$div = $div;
        this.color = color;
    }

    var rois = [
        new ROI($("#red"), "red"),
        new ROI($("#green"), "green"),
        new ROI($("#blue"), "blue"),                
        new ROI($("#yellow"), "yellow")
    ];

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        $.each(rois, function(index, roi){
            var $div = roi.$div;
            var color = roi.color; 
            if (scroll > $div.position().top){
                $("body").css("background-color", color);
            }
        }); 
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
body{
    height: 5000px;
}

.section{
    height: 400px;
}

.roi{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#red{
    background-color: red;
}

#green{
    background-color: green;    
}

#blue{
    background-color: blue; 
}

#yellow{
    background-color: yellow;   
}
```